# Cisco AXL 8.5 WSDL Java Import TranslationPattern

Tags: soap, wsimport, cisco-axl

This question is very specific. If CUCM, AXL and SOAP doesn't tell you anything, there's no need to read further. Except you're interested.

Has anyone been successful at `wsimport`ing the current WSDL file for Cisco AXL **and** supporting the `AddTransPattern`-Request? I'm talking     about version 8.5 or "current" (as in Cisco UCM 8.6.2).

The import was successful, but adding a translation pattern doesn't work anymore.

I tested it by writing my SOAP request by hand, using soapUI in eclipse.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.5">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:addTransPattern sequence="?">
            <transPattern>
                <pattern>MYPATTERN</pattern>
                <description>MYDESCRIPTION</description>
                <routePartitionName>MYPARTITION</routePartitionName>
                <calledPartyTransformationMask>MYDESTINATION</calledPartyTransformationMask>
                <provideOutsideDialtone>false</provideOutsideDialtone>
                <callingSearchSpaceName>MYCALLINGSEARCHSPACE</callingSearchSpaceName>
            </transPattern>
        </ns:addTransPattern>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

The response is as follows:

```
           <axlcode>-391</axlcode>
           <axlmessage>Cannot insert a null into column (numplan.tkpatternusage).</axlmessage>
           <request>addTransPattern</request>
```

soapUI tells me that putting `usage` is **optional**. Even if I put a value for usage, e.g. `<usage>3</usage>`, it tells me the value wouldn't exist even though I know it does.

Any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what was wrong.

The value for `<usage>` needs to be a string, like in this case `Translation`. Then it works without any problem.

Comment: The easiest way to determine this is to manually configure a API endpoint via the CUCM GUI, then do a `get` and see what's returned.